# Selenium WebDriver - Missing 'text' parameter (IndexOutOfBounds) - SendKeys

Tags: selenium, geckodriver

I'm trying to run a test on google's website and when I send the text I'm saying the following message:

Missing 'text' parameter (IndexOutOfBounds)

Code:
browser.FindElement(By.Name("q")).SendKeys("a");

What I do not understand is that until yesterday the code was running normally.

Can someone help me solve this error?

tks!

Version:
geckodriver-v0.16.0-win64
Selenium Client & WebDriver  - C#   3.4.0
Firefox 53.0v

Comment: Did you check if Google has changed the website?

Comment: Yes. The problem was automatic Firefox update to version 53.

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your Selenium.WebDriver and Selenium.Support packages to latest (v3.4.0). If you already have v3.4.0 make sure you have rebuilt all.

I just hit the same issue and updated v3.2.0 -> v3.4.0 and that fixed it for me.

(Just for context, I ended up with that error after getting 'Expected [object Undefined] undefined to be a string (IndexOutOfBounds)' following an automatic Firefox update to v53. The fix for *that* was to upgrade to geckodriver v0.16.0)

Comment: I am also facing this problem with FF 54 during sendkeys() method. This works for me...

Comment: I'm having the same issue. FF 63, Selenium.WebDriver 3.4.0 and geckodriver 0.22.0. I guess I'll have to wait for a patch...

Answer (score 0):

@Kayh and @NickBaker
There is still an issue: how did that work?

https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/511

I am using Firefox 53.0.3 (32-bit), geckodriver 0.16.1 to drive browser with Selenium 3.4.0 but still getting

> System.InvalidOperationException : Missing 'text' parameter (IndexOutOfBounds)

EDIT: 
https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/511 fixed now on 02 July 2017. Combination of Selenium client binding 3.4.3, geckodriver 0.17, Firefox 54 works now.